# ruby "class << self" might cause the error in gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, mechanize, httpcookie

I am trying to get use out of the "HTTP-Cookie" gem. Because I need it, working. But it seems that there is a Bug inside the Gem, and its not maintained for over one year.

The solution is: Make it yourself.
But my Ruby knowlege is limited on this point. (Otherwise i wouldn't use a gem for catching cookies..)

Here is the Problem:
If you try to import a existing YAML file into the program, it will raise this Error:

```
 7: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/http-cookie-1.0.3/lib/http/cookie_jar.rb:324:in `load'
    6: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/http-cookie-1.0.3/lib/http/cookie_jar.rb:324:in `open'
    5: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/http-cookie-1.0.3/lib/http/cookie_jar.rb:325:in `block in load'
    4: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/http-cookie-1.0.3/lib/http/cookie_jar/yaml_saver.rb:44:in `load'
    3: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/http-cookie-1.0.3/lib/http/cookie_jar/yaml_saver.rb:44:in `each'
    2: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/http-cookie-1.0.3/lib/http/cookie_jar/yaml_saver.rb:45:in `block in load'
    1: from C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/mechanize-2.7.5/lib/mechanize/cookie_jar.rb:22:in `add'
C:/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/http-cookie-1.0.3/lib/http/cookie_jar.rb:108:in `add': undefined method `acceptable?' for #<Hash:0x0000000006c9d758> (NoMethodError)
```

means: No method error, because the Method "acceptable?" can't be fount inside the cookie class. As I investigate that, I saw, that it is there. But it is not in the "class Cookie", it is in the "class << self".

As far as I understand, the << self shortcut means that code, which is inside the class is always "in the right class".
But the whole file is a require from the main gem file.

So my thoughts:

> 1. I use the load function that the gem provides
> 2. the gem require "cookie"(.rb).
> 3. Gem loads "Class self" but don't read the class as "cookie". It reads "class.self"
> 4. MRI tell me: we dont find a class cookie with the method "acceptable?".

My Questions:

1. Am I correct?
2. What can I do to fix this now? Renaming "class << self" into "class Cookie" will surely cause more problems then it fixes. Because it is a HUGH Class with more then 50 methods.

Comment: It's saying there's no average acceptable method on a hash. Are you sure you're using it right?

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer.
I hope so. It takes a yaml file. And the code for it is:

`code`
cookiefile = "kekstopf.yaml"
jar = HTTP::CookieJar.new
jar.load(cookiefile) if File.exist?(cookiefile)
`code`

Comment: Hi Tim! To figure out what's going on here we'd need to see your code (which generates this error) and the contents of the file you're trying to load (kekstopf.yaml). Also, did you save this file using the gem, or did it come from somewhere else?

Comment: Hi mike, thank you for answering.

Because I can't get behind the secret how to format anything nicely on stackoverflow, I post both files on pastebin.  https://pastebin.com/HwMquYCE (i altered the session ID's inside the session cookies.. you know why :D )

Comment: did you generate the yaml with the gem? there's a warning on the gem description regarding this

Answer (score 0):

According to the gem documentation there are known issues with YAML file formats see https://github.com/sparklemotion/http-cookie#file-formats

However you could just parse through you can use plain txt cookie format and just parse over your example yaml file so each line just contains the domain and values with no keys, space separated like so:

```
#cookie.txt
.springlane.de false false 1 pcah / no_restriction false true "0" QXVleEFoai8zR0xzJKHKJH56J5NUNkam5PbGVHenp6dz0K
.springlane.de 1526287010.834168 false false 2 pcar%5fUkVTV45RDMmA%3d%3d / no_restriction false false "0" K0lnSk94SGw1a1YiohzghbZrdfztUIOKHa25wZW03ek91RFJsK3R6a0I2YitpL0E5MFRTdEZ3PT0K

#and in your ruby script

require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
require 'open-uri'
require 'http-cookie'

agent = Mechanize.new { |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
}
cookiefile = "cookie.txt"
jar = HTTP::CookieJar.new
jar.load(cookiefile) if File.exist?(cookiefile)
seite = agent.get("https://www.springlane.de/magazin/rezeptideen/american-cookies-backen/")
seite.search('img').each {|n| puts "\n #{n}"}
```

Tested no exceptions.  If you wanna contribute to the gem in question, you'll need to write tests. But it seems like all you need is to write a conversion for your YAML file to standard cookie text format.